# can't find angular route js on google cdn

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cdn, ngroute

this may seem like a very basic question but I can't seem to find the route angular resources on the google developer cdn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.route.js) even though the official docs say to find it there (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/api/ngRoute)
I know I could use bower or npm to include them in my project, but I wanted to gain the benefits of static files served over a cdn (especially google's)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change the following...

> https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.route.js

to

> https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.js

difference?

`angular.route` => `angular-route`

Comment: argh! if my a$$ was detached from my body i'd kick it lol. thanks dude it's one of those days